# How is a speaker introduced at a Chinese mathematics conference?

Tags: spoken

I'm aiming to give a mathematics presentation at a conference next month (第八届全国组合数学与图论大会; [URL](http://ahuweb.ahu.cn/math/)).  Assuming everything goes to plan, this will be my first conference talk in Chinese (a 15-minute contributed talk), and my first conference presentation in Chinese.  It may be a total disaster, but I feel I should try (and learn from my mistakes).

At conferences, before the speaker talks, the session chair introduces them and their talk.  Usually it takes the format:

> I'd like to welcome [speaker's name] from [speaker's university] who will be talking on [talk title].

I'm not sure if this style differs within China (at non-international Chinese-speaking conferences), and what they would ordinarily say.

**Question**: How is a speaker introduced at a Chinese mathematics conference?

I'm seeking an example of an ordinary introduction at a Chinese mathematics conference to familiarize myself with what to expect.  It might be similar to above, e.g., perhaps I can expect something like:

> 欢迎来自南开大学的Rebecca Stones（中文叫李蓓），她将谈论＂枚举偏拉丁矩的四种方法＂．

However, I'm not sure if the format is the same.

At international conferences, sometimes a foreign speaker will repeat what the session chair has already said, e.g. beginning "My name is [speaker's name] and I'm from [speaker's university] and I will be talking on [talk title]."  It's a blooper, and I would like to avoid it.

---

*Edit*: To make sure this is clear: this question is about how the *session chair* would ordinarily introduce the speaker.  **The session chair is not the speaker; the session chair introduces the speaker.**  The question is not about how the speaker would introduce themself.  (My motivation is to react appropriately to how the session chair introduces me.)

Comment: That's really not a language problem, it more depends on the real life situation, you may use that at this conference but not another, you may use that in China but not Singapore. Please consider contacting with conference organizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 欢迎来自南开大学的Rebecca Stones（中文叫李蓓），她将谈论＂枚举偏拉丁矩的四种方法＂．

It should be the same as other conference, I guess. Normally, the words 欢迎 somebody will be put at the last sentence. Or the session host will say "让我们欢迎" somebody, or "下面有请" somebody "上台". And if the speaker is someone that important but not all the audience know, the host will also introduce the speaker's title and achievement a little bit.

It's hard to predict other people's words, but let's try a simple:

> 下面一位演讲者是来自南开大学的Rebecca Stones， 她的中文名是李蓓。她目前任教于南开大学计算机与控制工程学院，主要研究方向是xxx。曾经在xxx期刊发表过xxx论文。今天她将给大家介绍“枚举偏拉丁矩的四种方法”，让我们欢迎李蓓（有请李蓓/有请李蓓上台）。